# Connect to OracleDb using node.Js/ Strongloop without any C++ compiler? For connection, do we really need to compile source code everytime?

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am using Node.JS and IDE as webStorm. There are examples on connection to OracleDb using Node.Js but they need Python, C++ compiler, oracle Instant Client or "loopback-connector-oracle" when using Strongloop.

Is it really needed to compile source code everytime i need a connection??

Can we do it in easier way as we connect MongoDb in Node.Js?
Can't we simply pass on he URL string, name of Db, user and password to connect to OracleDb? may be using a simple plugable connector Driver.!?

Comment: Did you check npmjs.com registry for available packages? One I know about is https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

Comment: This is the same we tried and it is saying to compile the binaries from source code using python etc should the binaries available for ready to use instead of compiling everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Database driver for Node.js requires compilation when installing, not when getting a connection.

The team that works on the driver is exploring pre-built binaries but can't say if/when they will come. However, even with pre-built binaries, the need for the Instant Client will remain.

Hopefully things will get simpler over time... Till then we rely on some pretty good, platform and environment specific installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using Windows.  Check out the work on prebuilt Windows binaries for node-oracledb at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/18